# Storing lists within lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a question about accessing elements in lists.

This is the code:

```
movies = ["The Holy Grail", 1975, "Terry Jones and Terry Gilliam", 91,
          ["Graham Champman", ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]]]

print(movies[4][1][3])
```

And this is the output: `Eric Idle`

My question is why is the output `Eric Idle`? What does `4` represent, what do `1` and `3` represent? I'm so confused.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering Read this article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is separated into values.

```py
# movies: values
0. "The Holy Grail"
1. 1975
2. "Terry Jones and Terry Gilliam"
3. 91
4. ["Graham Champman", ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]]
```

**/!\ The index begin from 0**

The last value is also separated into values:

```py
# movies[4]: values
0. "Graham Champman"
1. ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]
```

And the last value is also separated into other values:

```py
# movies[4][1]: values
0. "Michael Palin",
1. "John Cleese"
2. "Terry Gilliam"
3. "Eric Idle"
4. "Terry Jones"
```

---

**So calling `movies[4]` returns the last element of `movies`:**

```
["Graham Champman", ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]]
```

**Typing `movies[4][1]` returns this:**

```
["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]
```

**And typing `movies[4][1][3]` returns that:**

```
"Eric Idle"
```

### Tree view

```
movies
 0. | "The Holy Grail"
 1. | 1975
 2. | "Terry Jones and Terry Gilliam"
 3. | 91
 4. |____
    4.0. | "Graham Champman"
    4.1. |____
        4.1.0 | "Michael Palin"
        4.1.1 | "John Cleese"
        4.1.2 | "Terry Gilliam"
        4.1.3 | "Eric Idle"
        4.1.4 | "Terry Jones"
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Please review [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with Python basics. Lists in Python can be indexed (starting with 0) and accessed using square brackets.

In your case, `sub_ele = movies[4]` is accessing the fifth element of the list movies, which is (in this case) a list of length two. Hence `subsub_ele = sub_ele[1]` is accessing the second element of the sub list, which is (in this case) a list of length five. Lastly, `subsub_ele[3]` is accessing the fourth element of the sub sub list, which is finally "Eric Idle".

Hopefully, it is now clear.