# too many indices for array inn while loop

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, while-loop, operators

I'm new in python and I'm not so good in writing code. this is my code :

```
N = len(data)
i = 0
j = 0
e = 10

while (i<N and j<339) :
                s[j] = data[i,1]
                i = i + 14
                j = j + 1
```

And I get this error :

```
16 while (i<N and j<339) :
---> 17                 s[j] = data[i,1]
     18                 i = i + 14
     19                 j = j + 1

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Please can someone help me resolve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess your `data` variable is a nested array? Then you have to access it like this: `data[i][1]`. Please post a sample `data` so that we can help better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing lists within lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788479/storing-lists-within-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

### You can only put one number in `[]`

**Assuming `data` is a 2-dimensionnal array:**

If you want to access to a value inside of an array inside of an array, put several pairs of `[]` like that:

```
s[j] = data[i][1]
```

The first pair of brackets will access to the array inside of data, then the second pair will access to a value inside of the sub array.

---

**[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788479/storing-lists-within-lists-in-python/66788589#66788589) (arrays inside of arrays)**

Answer (score 0):

The error resides in the syntax on the following line:

```
s[j] = data[i,1]
```

As the error says, you are trying to access the data array at 2 different indices, which results in an error

Answer (score -1):

I think use append method instead of index

```
s.append(data[i][1])
```